# Cannot start "yesod devel"

Tags: haskell, yesod

I've set up my environment as instructed in quick start guide (http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart) without any obvious troubles on my 64bit Window 7 machine.

I then run the following (which execute fine)

```
"yesod init" 
"cabal install --enable-tests --reorder-goals --max-backjumps=-1 -j"
```

However when I run "yesod devel" I find it stuck (not doing anything) showing following message:

```
> yesod devel
Yesod devel server. Press ENTER to quit
yesod: DeleteFile "C:\\Users\\USER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\10445.o": does
 not exist (The system cannot find the file specified.)
```

Mentioned temp file does not exist in the Temp folder.

I tried looking at yesod source code to see what it does but not sure if that helps:

```
putStrLn $ "Yesod devel server. "  ++ terminator ++ " to quit"
void $ forkIO $ do
  filesModified <- newEmptyMVar
  void $ forkIO $
    void $ watchTree manager "." (const True) (\_ -> void (tryPutMVar filesModified ()))
  evalStateT (mainOuterLoop develHsPath iappPort filesModified) Map.empty
after
writeLock opts
exitSuccess
```

Comment: Are there any logs that help identify the cause of the problem?

Comment: When I run `yesod devel` in verbose mode (-v) it doesn't give me any more output. Other than that I wouldn't know where to look for potential problems. Any advice?

Comment: 1) Is there a debug mode? It may not exist in documentation but only known to the development community; would recommend checking yesod's user forum to get it;
2) Try the 32bit version.
3) Change the DeleteFile value to a fixed folder with no tilda in the path.
4) Try installing on another computer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In order to proceed working with yesod I just switched to virtual Linux box. I gave up on trying to get it working on windows. Just curious what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as yours and I've even reported it: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/949

The problem gone after flushing the cabal package cache and rebuilding everything from scratch. This is definitely an environmental issue.

Also if you're experiencing anything like this, be sure to check `PATH` if there are some 3rd-party gcc installations in it.